# How to commit the changes from Server to GitHub in Magento?

Tags: github, webserver

We have three servers for our Magento site. They are as **Development**, **Staging** and **Live/Production**. We are doing the code changes directly on the server. For example, to edit the CSS and other code changes. Now we would like to use GitHub for collaborative work and to track the changes made on the server.

We have cloned the source of three servers to our GitHub account. As I said before, we are directly doing the code changes at the server. We want to commit the change which is made on a Development server to GitHub Development branch but we couldn't able to do it.

As of now, we have installed GitHub desktop and open the Development branch source on local and doing the code changes. Then after, we are committing changes to Development Brach. I'm aware this is not a correct workflow.

Could anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Did You set remote url after git init?

```
git remote add origin git@git.assembla.com:portfolio/space.space_name.git
#set a new remote
git remote -v
#Verify new remote
origin  git@git.assembla.com:portfolio/space.space_name.git (fetch)
origin  git@git.assembla.com:portfolio/space.space_name.git (push)
```